# Performance issue viewModelScope vs LaunchedEffect

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing simple animation from this article.
https://tech.okcupid.com/animate-on-a-path-with-android-jetpack-compose-ui-21d3249d0809

xOffset responsible for the animation is definied in my code the same like in the article.

```
var xState by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val xOffset = animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = xState,
    animationSpec = 
        tween(durationMillis = 4000, easing = LinearEasing)
)
```

Inside my setContent to update it's value I launched LaunchefEffect this way:

```
       LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                while (true) {
                    for (i in 0..360) {
                        delay(16)
                        xState += 1.dp
                    }

                }
            }
```

It's efficient and smooth and I like it. However I was trying to move this logic to view model and that is what I have. There I defined:

```
   private val _state: MutableStateFlow<Int> =
        MutableStateFlow(0)
    val state: StateFlow<Int>
        get() = _state

    fun updateState(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            while (true) {
                for (i in 0..360) {
                    delay(16)
                    _state.emit(i)
                }

            }
        }
```

And Fragment accordingly..

```
      viewModel.updateState()
                val state =   viewModel.state.collectAsState(context = Dispatchers.Main)
                val xOffset = animateDpAsState(
                    targetValue = state.value.dp,
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 4000, easing = LinearEasing)
                )
```

What is the difference, or what is causing performance issues?

Comment: `xState` just needs 2 states `0.dp` and `360.dp` - currently you are triyng to manually create an animation by updating it 60 times a second, then creating a new `animateDpAsState` everytime that changes ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - examples - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/quick-guide#animate-padding